# Vector Env with custom model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I've been reading about how to use vectorized environments with the SubProcVenv module
from [here](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/examples.html) and
[here](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/vec_envs.html).

However all the examples I can find use the stable baselines (openai's models) and I can't seem to find a way to do it with my custom model.

Can it be done? And how so?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as mentioned in the Colab notebook. I'm not sure what problem you are facing. The way I implemented for my custom environment is:

```
# Instantiate the env
env = customEnv()

# Wrap it
env = DummyVecEnv([lambda: env])

EPISODES = 5000
# Instantiate and learn using stable-baselines
model = PPO2('MlpPolicy', env).learn(EPISODES)
```

I'm sure you can do the same for `SubProcVenv` too. Go for `SubProcVenv` **only** if you want to use multiprocessing.